# Float number to 32 bits IEEE754 single precision is 64 bits

Tags: python, binary, type-conversion, ieee-754, bitstring

When using this code

```
import bitstring
f = 1.0e+00
b = bitstring.pack('>d', f)
b.bin
```

I get 64 bits

```
001111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But I need to get Float (IEEE754 Single precision 32-bit)

What is the >d used for?

Comment: The linked answer is correct, but your specific problem is that you should use `'>f'` instead of `'>d'` in your `pack`. See the [help](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/packing.html#compact-format).